# Calculating the angle of rotation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So i have the figure below:

[image]

and i want to **find the angle $a$** as shown in green. I have the coordinates of the blue points where

$x_i,y_i = (4,2)$ and $x_j,y_j = (4.3589, 1)$

According to the answer, $a$ is 13.6441 degrees, but i do not know how to work it out.

I used the formula

[image]

but I'm not getting the same answer.

Comment: I can see only ONE blue point in the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is fine, but you must switch your points, because $(x_1,y_1)$ in that formula refers to the point before rotation, which in your case is $(4.3589, 1)$, while $(x_2,y_2)$ refers to the point after rotation, which in your case is $(4, 2)$.

Comment: This should only flip the sign of the angle, no?

Comment: @MattiP. Yes, applying that formula with the points exchanged leads to $-13.6441°$.

Comment: Ah, now I recalculated:
$$
\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{2 \cdot 4.3589 - 4 \cdot 1}{4 \cdot 4.3589 + 2 \cdot 1} \right) \approx 13.6441^{\circ} 
$$

Comment: @Aretino strange, shouldn’t it be (4,2) for the point before rotation (black axis) and (4.3589,1) after rotation? Is the formula valid? Cause I found it in some other post.

Comment: @Maxxx Your rotation is counterclockwise: just draw both points in the diagram and check which one is the start and which is the end.